# Deleting from a database a selection in listbox

Tags: python, sqlite

I basically have 2 python scripts one is for frontend other is for backend. On Frontend I have this:

```
def delete_command():
    back.delete(selected_tuple[0])
```

So basically click on a entry in a listbox then on backend script it has the database call (sqllite3)

```
def delete(id):
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "AVDatabase.db")
    conn=sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('DELETE * FROM "Books"  where BookId=?',(BookId,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

But i keep getting an error:

```
cur.execute('DELETE * FROM "Books"  where BookId=?',(BookId,))
NameError: name 'BookId' is not defined
```

The database already exists so its not dynamically created not sure why it considers the `BookID` column as not defined, `BookID` is a primary key integer on the main Books Table.

Comment: I suggest you use sqlalchemy.

Comment: I have not use SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Where is **BookId**, the variable vs the table column, defined?  This seems to be complaining about the variable, not the contents of your SQL statement.  This is a compile-time error, not a runtime error, right?  It looks to me like that symbol simply isn't defined.

Comment: the Bookid is defined only as an entry widget which gets populated from a listbox. Basically i select an entry on the list box and wanted to pass say the BookID column off the Books Table to the Delete Statement.

Comment: BookId_text=IntVar()
entry1=Entry(window,textvariable=int(float(BookId_text.get())))
entry1.grid(row=1,column=1)

Comment: When i select from the listbox it goes above to the entry widget, thats the only place i can find a reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining `BookId`.

The `delete()` method requires a parameter named `id` and you are not using it anywhere in the definition.

replace `BookId` with `id` here:
`cur.execute('DELETE * FROM "Books"  where BookId=?',(BookId,))`
to
`cur.execute('DELETE * FROM "Books"  where BookId=?',(id,))`

```py
def delete(id):
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "AVDatabase.db")
    conn=sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('DELETE * FROM "Books"  where BookId=?',(id,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you that did it, Danke.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with what's in your database, or even with the SQL statement itself.  You just haven't defined **BookId**.  This code causes the same error:

```
class Cur:
    def execute(self, statement, values):
        pass

cur = Cur()
cur.execute('DELETE * FROM "Books"  where BookId=?',(BookId,))
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 10, in <module>
    cur.execute('DELETE * FROM "Books"  where BookId=?',(BookId,))
NameError: name 'BookId' is not defined
```

Change **BookId** to **id**, as @Powertieke says.